# What is the difference between "data mining" and "data analytics"?

Tags: data-mining, terminology, methodology

What is the difference between "data mining" and "data analytics"? Are both things the same technically?

Comment: I doubt there is any formal definition particularly for "data analytics", the words will just mean however people use them, & many people will use them in different ways. Your best bet for understanding the range of typical meanings it at the linked thread.

Comment: I associate data mining with not having any preconceived notions or research questions about the data (for example, no response variable has been chosen).